# Loops and Garbage Collection

Tags: .net, vb.net, garbage-collection, loops

I am working on a web application and I have run into the following situation.

```
Dim a as Object
Dim i as Integer = 0

Try

    For i=1 to 5

        a = new Object()

        'Do stuff '

        a = Nothing

    Next

Catch

Finally

   a = Nothing

End Try
```

Do i need to do the a=Nothing in the loop or will the garbage collector clean a up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In .NET, you generally do not **need** to set a variable reference = `Nothing` (`null` in C#). The garbage collector will clean up, eventually. The reference itself will be destroyed when it goes out of scope (either when your method exits or when the object of this class is finalized.) Note that this doesn't mean the **object** is destroyed, just the reference to it. The object will still be destroyed non-deterministically by the collector.

However, setting your reference = `Nothing` will provide a hint to .NET that the object may be garbage, and doesn't necessarily hurt anything -- aside from code clutter. If you were to keep it in there, I'd recommend removing it from `Try` block; it's already in the `Finally` block and will therefore always be called. (Aside from certain catastrophic exceptions; but in those cases it wouldn't get called in the `Try` block either!)

Finally, I have to admit that I agree with Greg: Your code would be cleaner without this. The hint to the runtime that you're done with the reference is nice, but certainly not critical. Honestly, if I saw this in a code review, I'd probably have the developer rewrite it thusly:

```
Dim a as Object
Dim i as Integer = 0

For i=1 to 5
    a = new Object()
    'Do stuff
Next
```

Comment: Actually setting the variable to null may cause the object's lifetime to be extended rather than shortened (http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/26/97229.aspx). Though the general message of the post is correct -- don't bother setting things to null.

Comment: Touche. The .NET JIT continues to surprise me with its intelligence and efficiency!

Answer (score 5):

It is almost never necessary to explicitly assign Nothing to a variable. The garbage collector's job is to take care of memory allocation for you, specifically to relieve you of this responsibility. So no, you don't need to assign `a = Nothing` inside the loop.

You also do not need the `try/finally` block that assigns Nothing around the whole thing. This is really just extra clutter that the runtime system will take care of anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need it. .NET has garbage collection. And since it looks like this code is in a method scope the garbage collection will clean up any local variables.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone stated above you do not need to explicitly set your variables to nothing, as it is handled automatically.  However, if for whatever reason you want to force the GC to collect, you can run this:

```
System.GC.Collect()
```

Comment: Forcing garbage collection is probably a really bad idea.  (It definitely is in Java!0